# Why am I getting ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, vercel

I am trying to create a page in my NextJS website for a blog post that I created. I am able to view the page correctly on my local machine but when I push to main for my production build I am getting this error. I can't figure out what to do to fix this error.
Here is the error:

```js
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/shelly-crying.jpg' in '/vercel/path0/pages/posts'
17:10:01.443    > Build error occurred
17:10:01.443    Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
17:10:01.444        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:17:924
17:10:01.444        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
17:10:01.444        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
17:10:01.444        at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
17:10:01.459    Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

And here is my structure:
[image: File structure of my site]

And here is the actual post `our-new-home.tsx`:

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";
import ShellyCrying from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/shelly-crying.jpg";
import NewTruck from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/new-truck.jpg";
import TrailerSold from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/trailer-sold.jpg";
import MessyLivingRoom from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/messy-living-room.jpg";
import MovingDay from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/snow-moving.jpg";
import LumpySleeping from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/lumpy-sleeping.jpg";
import CatalinaComforter from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/catalina-comforter.jpg";
import ShellyLumpy from "../../public/images/posts/our-new-home/shelly-lumpy.jpg";

export default function ourNewHome(): ReactElement {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto max-w-2xl p-4 md:p-0">
      <title>Our New Home</title>
      <article>
        <h1 className="text-5xl mb-4">Our New Home</h1>
        <p className="my-4">
          We are excited to share our next adventure! We both work remotely now,
          so we decided to take this opportunity to not be confined to a one
          bedroom, one bathroom insanely expensive apartment anymore. This was
          our chance to do something a bit non-traditional and we dove head
          first into researching how to make this happen before our lease was up
          in mid-April.
        </p>
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Step 1: The Essentials</h2>
        <p className="my-4">
          We quickly realized that we needed to decide what was essential to us
          in a home on wheels. We also had to decide what was better for us –
          something we could tow or something we could drive. These things were
          fairly easy to hash out. With my upbringing from an aeronautical
          engineer and bookkeeper and being married to a petroleum
          engineer/chemist, we did the only thing one can do – make a million
          Excel spread sheets! We are happily married and would like to continue
          to be for many years to come, so we decided we needed to have enough
          space to not be on top of each other. Other necessities - a bed that
          didn’t need to be folded up every day in order to have room to walk
          around, a bathroom with a door (some things need to be kept private,
          am I right!), work space, storage, a spot for a litter box, and a
          fully functioning kitchen. Bryan is a great cook and we wanted to be
          able to maintain our lifestyle of cooking most of our meals, having
          room to meal prep, and having a fridge that could hold a week’s worth
          of food. As for what led us to end up purchasing a travel trailer,
          there were a few things. One – price. We weren’t looking to spend
          hundreds of thousands of dollars on an RV, especially since we didn’t
          know if this lifestyle was going to be sustainable for us. Two –
          practicality of getting around. We knew that with our lifestyle it
          would be easier to drop our trailer and then explore, without worrying
          about where to park a 40+ foot recreational vehicle. Three – previous
          experiences. Bryan’s dad, Steve, had many RVs and there always seemed
          to be something wrong with the engine. We didn’t want to risk having
          the engine die and be in the shop for months. An RV in the shop isn’t
          that bad when you don’t live it in full time, but when it is your
          home, that would really put a damper on things. Given the popularity
          of traveling since COVID, it has become increasingly difficult to get
          parts and service. So maybe we were jaded, because of Steve, but we
          like to think that he was proud of us for learning from his life
          lessons.
        </p>
        <h2 className="mb-4 text-2xl font-semibold">
          Step 2: What vehicle is the best for towing a travel trailer?
        </h2>
        <p className="my-4">
          While I kept searching through thousands of travel trailers, I let
          Bryan take the lead on this step. We ended up upgrading from my 2008
          Volkswagen Jetta to a 2018 Ford F150 XLT 3.5 L EcoBoost. My Jetta was
          with me through vet school, got me from Florida to Chicago for my
          internship, back to Florida, out to Colorado, and many road trips in
          between. I’m quite certain she could have towed our TT with no trouble
          at all, but Bryan strongly disagreed, so I sadly traded her in one a
          cold, snowy day in March.{" "}
        </p>{" "}
        <img
          src={ShellyCrying}
          alt="Shelly saying her goodbyes to the Jetta"
          className=""
        />
        <p className="my-4">
          {" "}
          For previously not being a truck person, our new truck is a beauty.
          The EcoBoost is also incredibly dangerous. You can get up to 85 mph
          and not even realize it. However, towing 7,000 lbs will probably limit
          any potential speeding tickets in the near future. Our truck came with
          the trailer hitch and tow package, so that was one less thing we would
          need to add. With a weight distribution hitch and spring bars, our
          truck is rated to tow 10,500 pounds. Many YouTube videos later, we
          learned that you don’t really want to tow more than 75% of your tow
          capacity, so that gave us guidelines for trailer weight.
        </p>
        <img
          src={NewTruck}
          alt="Our new Ford F-150 EcoBoost"
          className="my-2"
        />
        <h2 className="my-4 text-2xl font-semibold">
          Step 3: Buy a travel trailer
        </h2>
        <p className="my-4">
          My Excel spreadsheet of potential travel trailers started out
          incredibly long and it soon become a bit overwhelming. There are just
          so many makes and models and most companies do a slight upgrade each
          year and completely change the model name. We visited a few
          dealerships in the area and were able to eliminate some styles (pop up
          camper on a windy day immediately eliminated any soft-sided models!)
          and also determine which companies were reputable. We painstakingly
          narrowed it down to two and finally settled on a Forest River Salem
          22RBS because of the weight, length, layout, interior design, price,
          and an insane amount of storage. We found one at the dealership Herold
          Trailer Sales in Indianola, Iowa. They took a deposit over the phone
          to hold it, but they were so backlogged, it would take close to 2
          months to do a proper inspection on it before it would be ready for
          pick up. We were out in Denver, so we took a chance that everything
          would be good to go by April and they were incredible about
          communicating with us via email over the next two{" "}
        </p>
        <img
          src={TrailerSold}
          alt="Our new Forest River 22RBS travel trailer"
          className="my-2"
        />
        <h2 className="my-4 text-2xl font-semibold">
          Step 4: Where are we going to put everything???
        </h2>
        <p className="my-4">
          Combined, we have moved 10 times in the past 11 years. And we aren’t
          talking just across town. Most of our moves have been across the
          country. This has prevented us from accumulating too much stuff, but
          things still have a way of accumulating. Now we had a new task in
          front of us – what was coming with us, what was going into storage,
          and what could we part with.{" "}
        </p>{" "}
        <img
          src={MessyLivingRoom}
          alt="Trying to declutter our messy living room"
          className="my-2"
        />
        <p className="my-4">
          {" "}
          Let’s just say I’m a huge fan of Marie Kondo, so we had no trouble
          thanking our things for the joy they brought us and then selling them
          on Facebook marketplace, giving them to friends, or donating them to
          Goodwill. It was incredibly therapeutic to declutter our lives. Mother
          nature also spiced things up a bit and made it snow on moving day!
        </p>
        <img
          src={MovingDay}
          alt="Snow covered truck with furniture in the back"
          className="my-2"
        />
        <h2 className="my-4 text-2xl font-semibold">
          Step 5: Sit our two cats down to ask them if they were ok with all of
          this
        </h2>
        <p className="my-4">
          By this point, they both realized something was up. Our normally tidy
          apartment was in disarray, new boxes of unfamiliar things were
          arriving daily, and there was stress in the air. After our new
          comforter arrived, they quickly gave me a sign that they were on board
          with this adventure.
        </p>
        <img
          src={LumpySleeping}
          alt="Lumpy Space Princess asleep on the new comforter"
          className="my-2"
        />
        <img
          src={CatalinaComforter}
          alt="Catalina Wine Mixer licking her lips on the new comforter"
          className="my-2"
        />
        <h2 className="my-4 text-2xl font-semibold">Step 6: Get inspired!</h2>
        <p className="my-4">
          All of this research and preparation were exhausting, but we still
          made time to get inspired by other full time travelers. Our favorite
          family to follow is Keep Your Daydream. If they can do it with three
          children and a dog, we can certainly do it with two adults and two
          cats, right? All of their tips, tricks, equipment lists, and travel
          ideas were invaluable and had us counting down the hours until move
          out day.
        </p>
        <h2 className="my-4 text-2xl font-semibold">
          Step 7: Drive to Indianola to get our new home
        </h2>
        <p className="my-4">
          Getting everything moved out and stored in the truck during a giant
          snow storm was less than ideal, but the day had arrived and it was
          time to travel to Iowa. It was a tight squeeze in the cab, but the
          cats loved their new carriers and we made it safely to Iowa.{" "}
        </p>
        <img
          src={ShellyLumpy}
          alt="Shelly with Lumpy in the truck on our way to pick up the trailer"
          className="my-4"
        />
      </article>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The site build only started to fail after I added the new post. It previously worked fine with all of the other pages.

Comment: The error is complaining about the images in `pages/posts` though. Shouldn't the path from `pages/posts` to the images in the `public` folder be something like `../public/images/<path>` instead? You can also reference the path directly in the `src` prop since they're [served statically from that folder](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving), e.g., `src="/images/posts/our-new-home/shelly-crying.jpg"`

Comment: The path for the page is `pages/posts/our-new-home.tsx` so I have to traverse two levels in the directory so I think the path I have is correct. It runs correctly on my local with that path.

Comment: As I mentioned, the error complains about `pages/posts.tsx` page, not `pages/posts/our-new-home.tsx`.

Comment: Switching to the static reference fixed it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Answer came from @juliomalves(see the comments section): [files statically served in public folder](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

I switched all of the `src=` links to the static reference ex:

```
<img src="/images/shelly-crying.jpg" />
```

production build went through after this change.